# Convert partial URL from parsed page to complete URL

Tags: python, urlparse

I'm crawling through a page which have incomplete URLs and I need to convert them to complete HTTP url, for example, the original address is: `http://www.example.com/dir1/dir1/` and the index file contains following links:

```
/page.htm
page.htm
../page.htm
../../page.htm
```

I need to convert them to

```
http://www.example.com/page.htm
http://www.example.com/dir1/dir2/page.htm
http://www.example.com/dir/page.htm
http://www.example.com/page.htm
```

I'm not sure how to recognize `../` and evaluate them from original address and `urlparse(temp_href).geturl()` doesn't work.

How to convert them correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

urljoin should do the trick for you.

```
from urlparse import urljoin

base = "http://www.example.com/dir1/dir1/"
print urljoin(base, "/page.htm")
print urljoin(base, "page.htm")
print urljoin(base, "../page.htm")
print urljoin(base, '../../page.htm')
```